# Localization of text outside of activities in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, localization, android-resources

I have an app with a clear distinction between domain, data, and presentation layers. I have my data model which is fetched from my server, which gets converted to a domain model and that is delivered to the presentation to be used for bindings and so on. I've been trying to localize my project. I have text that reads when a post was posted. eg. *"1 hour ago", "Moments ago"*...

I wanted to localize this and translate it but I cannot access string res from a data class without context. And I'd like to avoid passing context everywhere. How is this usually handled? It seems like a pretty common use-case of `getString`, but it seems I was wrong.

Comment: Application context is enough. Create an instance of, let's call it `ResourceProvider`, with the app context and use the provider in the data layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[getResources()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getResources()), which you need for the text localization, is the method of the abstract `Context` class. `Activity` just inherits it, meaning you don't actually need a reference to an `Activity` to get the package resources. Application context is enough.

As to using `Context` in a data layer, you might create an instance (better singleton) of, let's call it `ResourceProvider`, passing in the application context. For example,

```
interface ResourceProvider {
    fun getString(@StringRes id: Int): String
}

class ResourceProviderImpl constructor(private val context: Context) : ResourceProvider {

    override fun getString(id: Int): String = context.getString(id)
}
```

Just make sure you pass the [applicationContext](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getApplicationContext()) to the constructor of `ResourceProviderImpl` in order to avoid a memory leak on the context whose lifecycle is shorter than that of the application.

Comment: This solution won't respect language switch inside application, because you're using application context